# DELL, bluetoothctl, power on, No default controller available

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I just tried Debian and found that my bluetooth are not able to work. I have `bluez` and `blueman` installed, while `bluetoothctl` shows `No default controller available` respond.

```
bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

Bellow are my hardware condition details:

```
sudo lsusb; uname -a; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 064e:812c Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Linux localhost 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
bluetooth             374429  10 bnep,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
6lowpan_iphc           16588  1 bluetooth
rfkill                 18867  6 cfg80211,bluetooth,dell_laptop
crc16                  12343  2 ext4,bluetooth
[    0.131092] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    9.828699] usb 1-1.4: firmware: failed to load ar3k/AthrBT_0x31010000.dfu (-2)
[    9.828772] usb 1-1.4: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   19.146915] r8169 0000:09:00.0: firmware: failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw (-2)
[   19.147006] r8169 0000:09:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[   19.148582] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: unable to load firmware patch rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw (-12)
```

Your help will be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this help, https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/589128/3285

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on an Acer laptop. what I did was to grep through the `dmesg` output.

the line which looked most informative was:

```
usb 3-1.1: firmware: failed to load ar3k/AthrBT_0x11020000.dfu (-2)
```

looking for in on the internet I found [this q&a](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-laptop-and-netbook-25/bluetooth-not-loading-on-acer-c720-with-debian-4175502843/) which solved my problem.

in short:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-atheros
bluetooth-sendto ## (and escape to close the window)
```

the first installed the package I was missing, the second triggered the system to find the bluetooth device. when I again started `bluetoothctl`, it informed me that a controller was available, and the rest went as described in most documentation pages.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After a long research found out that the driver was not installed. Check that answer [Bluetooth doesn't work in debian 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545019/bluetooth-doesnt-work-in-debian-10) and see if your drivers are installed correctly =)